# $a$ and $b$ such that $a^k+b$ is never prime?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I recently saw a question in MSE asking if there are any relatively prime integers $a\not=1,b\not=0$ and such that $a^k+b$ will hit infinitely many primes, and the answer was that it's an **open problem** even for basic cases as $a=2,3$.

So my question is : **Is it known that for some $a,b$ it will never hit a prime?**

Comment: Sure. Just let $a=b$. Then $a^k+b=a(a^{k-1}-1)$ and it cannot be prime as long as neither $a$ or $a-1$ are prime.

Comment: @Frpzzd i will edit that they $(a,b)=1$.

Comment: Okay, then let $a$ be even and let $b$ be any even number that is not $1$ less than a prime, and is not zero. Then when $k=0$, $a^k+b$ is $b+1$, which is not a prime, and for all larger $k$, $a^k+b$ is even and greater than $2$, and thus cannot be prime.

Comment: @Frpzzd but then $gcd(a,b)=(a,b)\not=1$

Comment: Oh right. Then let $a$ and $b$ both be odd and relatively prime, and both not equal to one. Then $a^k+b$ is even and greater than two, and thus not prime.

Comment: @Frpzzd that is a beautiful answer !

Comment: $a=0$, $b=1$ are also relatively prime, and $0^k+1=1$ never hits a prime....

Comment: Oh come on... that is a trivial answer.

Comment: to say the least i was expecting an unusual answer like $a$ is odd and $b$ is even or vice-versa, so all these trivial solutions are good but not that great.

Comment: If there is a prime $p$ such that $a \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$ and $b \equiv -1 \pmod{p}$, then $a^k + b$ will always be a multiple of $p$. We can also find examples where there is no prime dividing all the $a^k + b$.

Comment: @DanielFischer that was not expected, thanks.

Comment: Just to be clear, I mainy posted my $0^k+1$ comment as an instructive joke.  The "instructive" part is that it's always a good idea, when trying to formulate a problem precisely, to check for trivial answers.  The OP had actually done this to a large extent in ruling out $a=1$ and/or $b=0$.

Comment: For example, for $a = 32$ and $b = 358423$ the number $a^k + b$ is never prime, and no prime divides all of these numbers.